# JSON Array to PHP DateTime

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony

How do I get PHP Date Time from a `JSON`?

```
$params = array();
 $content = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
 if(empty($content))
{
   throw $this->createNotFoundException('JSON not send!')
}
```

`$content['date']` need to be smomething like `$date = new DateTime();`

JSON looks like :

```
{
    "date" : "2017-02-15 15:20:14"
}
```

Comment: date is coming through your json code??

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. JSON looks like: { "date" : "2017-02-15 15:20:14" }

Comment: that is coming right then directly you will access what is the problem??

Comment: Sorry i´m new. I want to add the date into my database with Doctrine.

Comment: Something like this you want:- https://eval.in/738426

Comment: so decode the json response and get the date and store in database...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `echo "<pre/>";print_r($content);` is given data like below:-

```
Array
(
    [date] => 2017-02-15 15:20:14
)
```

So do like below:-

```
echo date ('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($content['date'])); // normal date conversion

echo PHP_EOL;

$dateTime = new DateTime($content['date']); // datetime object

echo $dateTime->format('y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output:-https://eval.in/738434

Comment: important to know: if `$content['date']` is `null` for any reason or not in a correct format, `DateTime()` will most probably provide you with an unexpected date (e.g. for null it's now).

Answer (score 3):

The date you're getting from JSON is coming in as a string, so you'll need to build a DateTime object from that string. As long as the string is in a format recognised by PHP's date and time formats (http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) you can do it very simply as follows:

```
$date = new DateTime($content['date']);
```